# Make a loading message created with withLoader() of shinycustomloader dynamic

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which if I give a name except of the default `consent.name`, then press `Continue` and will be moved in the tabItem `Password` in which I give the password `makis` and press the `Get started` actionbutton in either `Welcome` or `Run Project` tab an rmd output is generated.
As you will see while the report is being created a loading message is displayed in the `Results` tab. The issue is that if someone press the `Get started` actionButton() before filling the inputs in `consent.name` and `password` the loading message is being displayed in the `Results` tab but it has no meaning. So basically Im looking for a way to activate it only when the correct `password` and `consent.name` are given. I know that the loading message comes from the `withLoader()` function of `shinycustomloader` and I wonder how I can make it dynamic. Or probably adapt the `actionButton` that activates it somehow.

the ex.rmd

```
---
title: "An example Knitr/R Markdown document"
output: pdf_document
---


{r chunk_name, include=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x, y)
```

and the app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(knitr)
library(shinycustomloader)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:-35px; padding: 0px 90px 0px 1250px ;font-size: 58px ;color: black;font-family:Times-New Roman;font-weight: bold; width: 500px;",HTML(mytitle)),
    div(style="display: inline;margin-top:25px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 1250px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("well", "Welcome")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("pswd", "Password")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("rp", "Run Project")),
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("res", "Results"))
    
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Welcome", tabName = "well", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart")),
                                           menuItem("Password", tabName = "pswd", icon = icon("house")),
                                           menuItem("Run Project", tabName = "rp", icon = icon("table")),
                                           menuItem("Results", tabName = "res", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      tabItems(
        tabItem("well",
                fluidRow(),
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,
                         actionButton("button", "Get started",style='padding:4px; font-size:140%')))),
        
        tabItem("conse",
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(column(3,textInput("name", label = ("Name"), value = "consent.name"))),
                fluidRow(column(3,actionButton('continue', "Continue",style='padding:4px; font-size:180%')))
        ),
        tabItem("pswd",
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(5,),
                  column(6,passwordInput("pwd", "Enter the Database browser password")
                         
                         
                  )) ),
        tabItem("rp"),
        tabItem("res",
                tags$hr(),
                tags$hr(),
                
                fluidRow(
                  column(3
                         
                  ),
                  column(6,
                         withLoader(uiOutput('markdown'),type="html",loader = "loader1"))))
      ),
      
      
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
    observeEvent(input$button,{
      if (input$name=="consent.name"){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          output$markdown <- renderUI({
            HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit('ex.rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
          })
          
        }
        else{
          return(NULL)
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$well, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "well")
    })
    observeEvent(input$conse, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "conse")
    })
    observeEvent(input$pswd, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "pswd")
    })
    observeEvent(input$rp, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "well")
    })
    observeEvent(input$res, {
      updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "res")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      if (input$name=="consent.name") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd==""){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        else if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
        }
        else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        
      }
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$continue, {
      if (input$name=="consent.name") {
        updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                       selected = "conse")
      }
      else{
        if(input$pwd==""){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        else if(input$pwd=="makis"){
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "res")
        }
        else{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar",
                         selected = "pswd")
        }
        
      }
      
    })
    
   
  }
  )
)
```